# How to get 5 latest post for each genre Laravel API?

Tags: php, mysql, angular, laravel, api

I'm building an application (my course project) with Laravel 5.4 as API and Angular 5. My project is a music blog. I need to fulfill requirements such as to have *categories and subcategories*.

So, I have **genres, bands and posts**. For my home page **I want to display 5 latest posts for each category**.

**My tables**

- genres(id, name, slug);
- bands(id, name, slug, genre_id);
- posts(id, title, content, band_id, slug, created_at, updated_at).

**My relationships**

**Genre.php**

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];

public function bands()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Band');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Post', 'App\Models\Band');
}
```

**Band.php**

```
protected $fillable = ['name','slug','genre_id'];

public function genre()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Genre');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
}
```

**Post.php**

```
protected $fillable = ['title','content','image','band_id','slug'];

public function band()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Band');
}
```

**In my HomeController I've tried:**

```
$latest5PostsPerGenre = Genre::with([
        'posts' => function($query) {
            $query->take(5)
                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                  ->get(['posts.id', 'title']);
        }])->orderBy('name')
           ->get();
```

But it limits the total number of posts to 5 I got for all genres. So, some genres don't have posts at all.

---

```
$latest5PostsPerGenre = Genre::with('latest5Posts')
                        ->orderBy('name')
                        ->get();
```

with such methods in Genre model:

```
public function latest5Posts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Post', 'App\Models\Band')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->take(5)
        ->get();
}

or

public function latest5Posts()
{
    return $this->posts()->latest()->take(5)->get();
}
```

But I got *BadMethodCallException Method addEagerConstraints does not exist*.

---

I even tried something like this:

```
        $genres = Genre::with('posts')->orderBy('name')->get();
    $latest5PostsPerGenre = [];

    foreach ($genres as $genre) {
        $genrePosts['posts'] = [];
        $posts = $genre->posts()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $singePost = [];

            $singePost['id'] = $post->id;
            $singePost['title'] = $post->title;
            $singePost['bandName'] = $post->band->name;

            array_push($genrePosts['posts'], $singePost);
        }

        array_push($latest5PostsPerGenre[$genre->name], $genrePosts);
    }
```

or like this

```
$genres = Genre::get();
foreach ($genres as $genre) { 
        $post[$genre->name] = $genre->posts()
                                    ->take(5)
                                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                                    ->get();
```

}

But I understand it performs a lot of queries to db and is not right.

---

I tried to create method **scopeNPerGroup** in **Model.php** according to the link https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/, but it gives be a bunch of sql errors.

---

I was thinking about some complex, nested sql query with Eloquent, but don't clearly understand how to write it.

As a result, I'm expecting to have each genre name with 5 latest posts containing id, title and band name for each post in order to write the link for each post in my Angular frontend like *rnmblog.com/api/{genre-slug}/{band-slug}/{post-id} or {post-slug}* to get single post.

Comment: Are Categories and Genres different tables?

Comment: fixed the code. that code was from another stackoverflow page.

Answer (score 0):

> For my home page I want to display 5 latest posts for each category.

Your first attempt already does this, isn't it? Just improved it a bit

```
$latest5PostsPerGenre = Genre::with([ 
    'posts' => function($query) { 
        $query->with('bands')
            ->take(5)
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc') 
            ->get(); 
    }])
    ->orderBy('name') 
    ->get();
```

Comment: We can’t limit posts to 5 per category this way. All we did is limiting whole query to 5 posts. I receive such json:
"id": 2,
            "name": "alternative rock",
            "slug": "alternative-rock",
            "posts": [
                {
                    "id": 399,
                    "title": "A explicabo voluptates at sed nemo et.",
                    "genre_id": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "hard rock",
            "slug": "hard-rock",
            "posts": []
        },

Comment: Why can't you limit posts this way? Because I thought you want to display "5 posts" per category and that's what your code already does.

Comment: hmm...I was thinking that way too)) but really it doesn't. I tested with Postman. For now I have 6 genres -> it shall give me 5*6=30 posts in total, but I receive: 1 genre - 1 post, 2 genre - [ ], 3 genre - 2 post, 4 genre - 2 posts, 5 genre - [ ], 6 genre - [ ]. 
https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/ - here is written why (4 and 5 paragraph). I already tried it.

Comment: Are you sure that all of your `genres` contains at least 5 posts each?

Comment: Of course, each genre contains more than 50-60 posts.